# Cassandra CQL Shell stop displaying rows

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am wondering is there a command to stop displaying MORE rows from the CQL Shell. I created a table and inserted with 100k rows, so every time `select * from test_table` will display 100k rows, with MORE rows shown by pressing the Enter key. So I have to close the window and start the shell again.

I am using `Cassandra` on `Windows 10 X64`.

Comment: a simple `Ctrl+c` works for me!

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan that seems to be the only viable solution.

Comment: ctrl+c for some reason screws the next query: it will always return nothing. I need to run the query twice after a ctrl+c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable paging in cqlsh using the PAGING OFF command
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/paging.html

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is technically running your program (the query) so to kill it just press

`ctrl -c`

like you would to terminate any other command